How to Include and Apply stylecop.json and Custom Ruleset in a NuGet Analyzer Package
This post is a follow-up from this How to create nuget package with Stylecop Analyzer and custom ruleset?
I am currently working on a nuget package with custom analyzers, a stylecop.json, and a Custom.ruleset with referencing to stylecop analyzer. This package serves as a consistent style guideline in all our team projects.
I have created my solution based on the Visual studio template Analyzer with Code Fix (.NET Standard).
I removed the .CodeFixes, .Test and .VSIX project and moved the CodeFixes into the main Analyzer.csproj project. Those work fine.
Now I want to add a stylecop.json and a Custom.ruleset to my nuget package, which also checks for warnings and highlight them in the project where the nuget package will be installed.

I added the references in the .csproj files like so:
MyAnalyzer.csproj
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="stylecop.json" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" Pack="true" PackagePath="content"/>
  <None Include="Custom.ruleset" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" Pack="true" PackagePath="content"/>
</ItemGroup>

MyAnalyzer.Package.csproj
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyAnalyzer\MyAnalyzer.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\MyAnalyzer\stylecop.json" Pack="true" PackagePath="contentFiles/any/any/stylecop.json" />
    <Content Include="..\MyAnalyzer\Custom.ruleset" Pack="true" PackagePath="contentFiles/any/any/Custom.ruleset" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="..\MyAnalyzer\stylecop.json" Pack="true" PackagePath="content/stylecop.json" />
    <None Include="..\MyAnalyzer\Custom.ruleset" Pack="true" PackagePath="content/Custom.ruleset" />
</ItemGroup>

Sadly this does not work.
To generate the .nupkg file I do:
\MyAnalyzer> dotnet build -c Release

\MyAnalyzer.Package> dotnet build -c Release
\MyAnalyzer.Package> dotnet pack -c Release
\MyAnalyzer.Package> copy bin\Release\MyAnalyzer.1.0.1.nupkg C:\LocalNuGetFeed

\MyTestProject> dotnet add package MyAnalyzer --version 1.0.1 --source C:\LocalNuGetFeed

If I look at the .nuspec file inside the generated .nupkg it looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyAnalyzer</id>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    ...
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any/any/stylecop.json" buildAction="Content" />
      <files include="any/any/Custom.ruleset" buildAction="Content" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>

The PackageReference in my testProject after adding the nuget package is this:
 <PackageReference Include="MyAnalyzer" Version="1.0.2">
   <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
   <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
 </PackageReference>

I tried to research this specific case, but I had no luck. Does someone have any idea on what to try?

You can look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267268/add-code-analysis-ruleset-through-nuget-package

@akshay_zz Yes, I saw this thread too but I couldn't get it to work. I always get the error in my TestProject after importing: Could not find rule set file "TestProject.CodeAnalysis.ruleset". (my file is called Custom.ruleset)
